# Google Secrets in Firebase Function V2 Document Trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a question about Firebase Functions V2, with regards to how to include Google Secrets Manager into the document trigger function.

I know how to do it with OnRequest, the below works fine.

```
exports.myWebhook = onRequest({secrets: [MY_WEBHOOK_SECRET, MY_TEST_SECRET_KEY]}, async (req, res) => {
    const safe = STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY.value();
}
```

However I can't seem to get it to work with onDocumentCreated...

```
exports.myUpdate = onDocumentCreated("/orders/{documentId}", async (event ) => {
 const myAPIKey = MY_OTHER_API.value()
}
```

Any time I place {secrets: [MY_OTHER_API]} anywhere in this function, it creates an error. If I exclude it then the API key value is just blank.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Tried placing {secrets: [MY_OTHER_API_KEY]} into the function to allow it access to the Google Secret value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per the [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.md#firestoreondocumentcreated_2), the first parameter is either a document path or a [`firestore.DocumentOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.documentoptions.md#firestoredocumentoptions_interface) object (which extends [`GlobalOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptions_interface) where `secrets` is defined):

```js
exports.myUpdate = onDocumentCreated(
  {
    document: "/orders/{documentId}",
    secrets: [MY_OTHER_API]
  },
  async (event) => {
    const myAPIKey = MY_OTHER_API.value()
    // other steps
  }
)
```

Comment: I guess that's the limitations of being a self taught coder vs a professional developer. I'm staring at that API reference and still would have had no clue it was the answer to my problem :-P . Your example was perfect and my API calls are now executing, thanks a lot!