# How do we configure timeout and memory for a gen 2 Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

For older functions i was able to do this:

`functions.runWith({timeoutSeconds: 120, memory: "1GB"})`

How do we do this for a 2nd generation `https.onCall()` function?

There does not seem to be any detailed instruction for this anywhere in Firebase's documentation other than:

1. A [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade) here that does not cover `https.onCall()` functions
2. A [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) here that also does not cover `https.onCall()` functions

[This SO reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76360867/google-secrets-in-firebase-function-v2-document-trigger) is **NOT** a duplicate given that it does not refer to setting an increase for the timeout nor the memory for an `onCall()` function.

I was not able to find any question on SO specific to this exact question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set the increase inside the `firebase.json` configuration file as follows, whereas `FUNCTION_NAME` would need to be set to the name of the exported function in my source code:

`export const FUNCTION_NAME = functions.https.onCall( async (request:any) => {`

```
"functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ],
      "v2": {
        "source": "functions",
        "runtime": "nodejs16",
        "api_version": 2,
        "endpoints": {
          "FUNCTION_NAME": {
            "platform": "gcfv2",
            "region": "us-central1",
            "availableMemoryMb": 1024,
            "timeoutSeconds": 120
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is possible to simply set both as the first argument of `onCall()` although i am not able to find this in Firebase's documentation:

`export const FUNCTION_NAME = functions.https.onCall({timeoutSeconds: 120, memory: "2GiB"}, async (request:any) => {`

Comment: The API Reference is the primary source for documentation. The build guides assist reading the reference. The API Reference for [GlobalOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptions_interface) is provided in the linked thread. In the comments of the question you have now deleted, I also linked to the API Reference for [`onCall(opts, handler)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.https.md#httpsoncall) which accepts the `GlobalOptions` object as its first parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately the build guides are not updated as often, and as thoroughly, as they should be. Every build guide has "Was this helpful?"/"Send Feedback" actions in the top right corner of the page. I encourage you to submit your feedback to the team to get this added.